# Configuring http:localhost for Golang

Tags: http, go, iis, localhost

I would like to realize some tutorials in Golang which covers net/http library and other web and routing libraries as well. Besides, I use my localhost to test my asp.net core with IIS. I have already stopped my IIS client on my machine and it still redirects me to IIS themed localhost instead of showing my golang Fprintf message.The page on my localhost, my current iis settings, and the golang code can be seen below. Any help would be appreciated.

The page on http:localhost
[image: my localhost on the browser]

My IIS situation summary(It is stopped manually)
[image: my iis situation]

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        numOfBytesWritten, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, World!")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "Error occured!")
        }

        fmt.Fprintln(w, numOfBytesWritten, " bytes written.")
        http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    })
}
```

My sites on ISS.
[image]

Comment: Use port :8080 and use http://localhost:8080 in the browser.

Comment: You are calling ListenAndServe in the handler function. Call it in main instead and also don't ignore the error it returns.

Comment: The program is not throwing any error.

Comment: Using port 80:80 did not make any changes.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The supposedly duplicated question mentioned is about running a Go applcation on IIS, while this question is about running a Go application on localhost in Windows. There's a difference. The other question did not solve my issue, but this one does. Could somebody with priveleges please vote to reopen this question?

Answer (score -1):

My mistake was silly :)

```
http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
```

line should not be inside `http.HandleFunc()`. So my final code is below and it works as expected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        n, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!\n")
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d bytes written\n", n)
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error occured.")
        }
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Make sure **Default Web Site** is not running, looks like you stopped something else.

See the attached image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMhjP.png

Comment: It is not running already.

Comment: go to Command Prompt and stop it right there comand:  iisreset /stop